# how can get unique data like the fingerprint in flutter web of the data of WebBrowserInfo of device_info_plus package

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-web

I want to get unique data in flutter web of Browser the data in device_info_plus package is

```
Map<String, dynamic> _readWebBrowserInfo(WebBrowserInfo data) {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'browserName': describeEnum(data.browserName),
      'appCodeName': data.appCodeName,
      'appName': data.appName,
      'appVersion': data.appVersion,
      'deviceMemory': data.deviceMemory,
      'language': data.language,
      'languages': data.languages,
      'platform': data.platform,
      'product': data.product,
      'productSub': data.productSub,
      'userAgent': data.userAgent,
      'vendor': data.vendor,
      'vendorSub': data.vendorSub,
      'hardwareConcurrency': data.hardwareConcurrency,
      'maxTouchPoints': data.maxTouchPoints,
    };
  }
```

and do not know what can be unique like fingerprint in android data

Comment: Hi there, at the end is you solve it?